# Custom modal presentation with floating bottom bar

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewanimationtransition

I have an unusual UI requirement that I believe requires a custom modal presentation style, of some sort. I effectively need a floating bottom bar combined with the default pageSheet animation, for an iPad only app.

Everything about the pageSheet presentation style is perfect, except that I need to put a floating bottom bar below the presented view controller.

When the view controller gets presented, it should come up from the bottom, and *underneath*, the floating bottom bar. Likewise, on dismissal, it should come down from the top and transition underneath the bottom bar.

Mockups:
[image]

I have no intention of reinventing any wheels here, so any existing libraries / GitHub projects are acceptable; however, assuming there aren't any, what is the best way to do this? I'm not even sure if I'm thinking in the right direction since the floating bottom bar should be present not only before the presentation, but also during, and after. Moreover, the content on the bar must be interactable at all times (with the exception, perhaps, while the animation is in progress).

Full disclaimer, I am not an expert when it comes to custom transitions/presentation styles, so any help is appreciated.

Edit: Code examples are welcomed, but not required. I'm very much interested in the basic mechanics/structure of a feature like this.

Comment: I'm assuming you want "Floating control bar" to be active? That is, you want to be able to tap on buttons, etc in the control bar whether `PresentedVC` is visible or not? If so, you probably don't want to try and do that with modal presentation. Instead, load `PresentedVC` as a **child view controller**, add its view as a subview *behind* floatingControlBar and off the bottom of the view (screen), then animate it into position.

Comment: @DonMag Yep, that sounds pretty reasonable if there's no easy/good way to do it with the modal presentation. Thanks. Maybe I'm just overthinking this...

Comment: Yep... pretty much, **modal**, by definition, means *put this in front of everything else, and don't allow interaction with anything underneath it*.